Not working ZK4500 to save new fingers data in C#
I am learning to develop the functionality for this ZK4500 fingerprint scanner with C# to save the finger data into a .dat file. As I launch this for first time (there is no .dat file yet), i can add as many fingers as I want. But, if I close this and open it again to add a new finger, it says "Enroll failed, error code=-13" even when the previously enrolled fingers are there there.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using libzkfpcsharp;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using Sample;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        IntPtr mDevHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr mDBHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr FormHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool bIsTimeToDie = false;
        bool IsRegister = false;
        bool bIdentify = true;
        byte[] FPBuffer;
        int RegisterCount = 0;
        const int REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT = 3;

        byte[][] RegTmps = new byte[3][];
        byte[] RegTmp = new byte[2048];
        byte[] CapTmp = new byte[2048];
        int cbCapTmp = 2048;
        int cbRegTmp = 0;
        int iFid = 1;
        Thread captureThread = null;

        private int mfpWidth = 0;
        private int mfpHeight = 0;

        const int MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK = 0x0400 + 6;
        private const string FINGERPRINT_DATA_FILE = "fingerprint_template.dat";


        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bnInit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmbIdx.Items.Clear();
            int ret = zkfperrdef.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
            if ((ret = zkfp2.Init()) == zkfperrdef.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
            {
                int nCount = zkfp2.GetDeviceCount();
                if (nCount > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
                    {
                        cmbIdx.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                    }
                    cmbIdx.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    bnInit.Enabled = false;
                    bnFree.Enabled = true;
                    bnOpen.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    zkfp2.Terminate();
                    MessageBox.Show("No device connected!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Initialize fail, ret=" + ret + " !");
            }
        }

        private void LoadFingerprintData()
        {
            if (File.Exists(FINGERPRINT_DATA_FILE))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FINGERPRINT_DATA_FILE, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
                        {
                            while (fs.Position < fs.Length)
                            {
                                int fid = reader.ReadInt32(); // Read the fingerprint ID
                                int templateLength = reader.ReadInt32(); // Read the length of the template
                                byte[] template = reader.ReadBytes(templateLength); // Read the template

                                // Add the loaded fingerprint template to the database
                                int ret = zkfp2.DBAdd(mDBHandle, fid, template);
                                if (ret == zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
                                {
                                    textRes.Text = $"Fingerprint with ID {fid} loaded successfully.";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    textRes.Text = $"Failed to add fingerprint with ID {fid}. Error: {ret}";
                                }

                                // Update the fingerprint ID counter so it doesn't conflict
                                iFid = fid + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    textRes.Text = "Error loading fingerprint data: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                textRes.Text = "No saved fingerprint data found.";
            }
        }

        private void SaveFingerprintData(int fid, byte[] fingerprintTemplate)
        {
            try
            {
                // Open file in append mode
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FINGERPRINT_DATA_FILE, FileMode.Append))
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                    {
                        writer.Write(fid); // Write fingerprint ID
                        writer.Write(fingerprintTemplate.Length); // Write the length of the fingerprint template
                        writer.Write(fingerprintTemplate); // Write the fingerprint template itself
                    }
                }
                textRes.Text = "Fingerprint data saved successfully.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textRes.Text = "Error saving fingerprint data: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }

        private void bnFree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            zkfp2.Terminate();
            cbRegTmp = 0;
            bnInit.Enabled = true;
            bnFree.Enabled = false;
            bnOpen.Enabled = false;
            bnClose.Enabled = false;
            bnEnroll.Enabled = false;
            bnVerify.Enabled = false;
            bnIdentify.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void bnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
            if (IntPtr.Zero == (mDevHandle = zkfp2.OpenDevice(cmbIdx.SelectedIndex)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OpenDevice fail");
                return;
            }
            if (IntPtr.Zero == (mDBHandle = zkfp2.DBInit()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Init DB fail");
                zkfp2.CloseDevice(mDevHandle);
                mDevHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }

            // Load fingerprint data only after the device and DB are successfully initialized
            LoadFingerprintData();

            bnInit.Enabled = false;
            bnFree.Enabled = true;
            bnOpen.Enabled = false;
            bnClose.Enabled = true;
            bnEnroll.Enabled = true;
            bnVerify.Enabled = true;
            bnIdentify.Enabled = true;
            RegisterCount = 0;
            cbRegTmp = 0;
            iFid = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                RegTmps[i] = new byte[2048];
            }
            byte[] paramValue = new byte[4];
            int size = 4;
            zkfp2.GetParameters(mDevHandle, 1, paramValue, ref size);
            zkfp2.ByteArray2Int(paramValue, ref mfpWidth);

            size = 4;
            zkfp2.GetParameters(mDevHandle, 2, paramValue, ref size);
            zkfp2.ByteArray2Int(paramValue, ref mfpHeight);

            FPBuffer = new byte[mfpWidth * mfpHeight];

            captureThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoCapture));
            captureThread.IsBackground = true;
            captureThread.Start();
            bIsTimeToDie = false;
            textRes.Text = "Device opened successfully.";
        }

        private void DoCapture()
        {
            while (!bIsTimeToDie)
            {
                cbCapTmp = 2048;
                int ret = zkfp2.AcquireFingerprint(mDevHandle, FPBuffer, CapTmp, ref cbCapTmp);
                if (ret == zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
                {
                    SendMessage(FormHandle, MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }

        protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK:
                    {
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        BitmapFormat.GetBitmap(FPBuffer, mfpWidth, mfpHeight, ref ms);
                        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                        this.picFPImg.Image = bmp;

                        if (IsRegister)
                        {
                            int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
                            int fid = 0, score = 0;
                            ret = zkfp2.DBIdentify(mDBHandle, CapTmp, ref fid, ref score);
                            if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == ret)
                            {
                                textRes.Text = "This finger was already registered by " + fid + "!";
                                return;
                            }
                            if (RegisterCount > 0 && zkfp2.DBMatch(mDBHandle, CapTmp, RegTmps[RegisterCount - 1]) <= 0)
                            {
                                textRes.Text = "Please press the same finger 3 times for the enrollment";
                                return;
                            }
                            Array.Copy(CapTmp, RegTmps[RegisterCount], cbCapTmp);
                            RegisterCount++;
                            if (RegisterCount >= REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT)
                            {
                                RegisterCount = 0;
                                if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == (ret = zkfp2.DBMerge(mDBHandle, RegTmps[0], RegTmps[1], RegTmps[2], RegTmp, ref cbRegTmp)) &&
                                       zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == (ret = zkfp2.DBAdd(mDBHandle, iFid, RegTmp)))
                                {
                                    iFid++;
                                    textRes.Text = "Enroll successful";
                                    SaveFingerprintData(iFid - 1, RegTmp); // Use iFid - 1 because it's incremented after adding
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    textRes.Text = "Enroll failed, error code=" + ret;
                                }
                                IsRegister = false;
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                textRes.Text = "You need to press the " + (REGISTER_FINGER_COUNT - RegisterCount) + " times fingerprint";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (cbRegTmp <= 0)
                            {
                                textRes.Text = "Please register your finger first!";
                                return;
                            }
                            if (bIdentify)
                            {
                                int ret = zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
                                int fid = 0, score = 0;
                                ret = zkfp2.DBIdentify(mDBHandle, CapTmp, ref fid, ref score);
                                if (zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK == ret)
                                {
                                    textRes.Text = "Identify succ, fid= " + fid + ",score=" + score + "!";
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    textRes.Text = "Identify failed, ret= " + ret;
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int ret = zkfp2.DBMatch(mDBHandle, CapTmp, RegTmp);
                                if (0 < ret)
                                {
                                    textRes.Text = "Match finger succ, score=" + ret + "!";
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    textRes.Text = "Match finger failed, ret= " + ret;
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    base.DefWndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormHandle = this.Handle;
        }

        private void CloseDevice()
        {
            if (IntPtr.Zero != mDevHandle)
            {
                bIsTimeToDie = true;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                captureThread.Join();
                zkfp2.CloseDevice(mDevHandle);
                mDevHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        private void bnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloseDevice();
            RegisterCount = 0;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            bnInit.Enabled = false;
            bnFree.Enabled = true;
            bnOpen.Enabled = true;
            bnClose.Enabled = false;
            bnEnroll.Enabled = false;
            bnVerify.Enabled = false;
            bnIdentify.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void bnEnroll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsRegister)
            {
                IsRegister = true;
                RegisterCount = 0;
                cbRegTmp = 0;
                textRes.Text = "Please press your finger 3 times!";
            }
        }

        private void bnIdentify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!bIdentify)
            {
                bIdentify = true;
                textRes.Text = "Please press your finger!";
            }
        }

        private void bnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bIdentify)
            {
                bIdentify = false;
                textRes.Text = "Please press your finger!";
            }
        }
    }
}


I have to make sure Save and Load iFid Correctly
iFid = fid + 1;

What I want is, to be able to add and save other finger data even if I close and open the app again.

It fixed now, Remove this line from bnOpen_Click:
iFid = 1;

